# Implementing a mutable ranking table in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, dictionary, stl

In an event-driven simulator, I need to keep track of the popularity of a large number of content elements from a catalog. More specifically I am interested in knowing the rank of any given content, i.e. its position in a list sorted by descending number of requests. I know that the number of requests per content is only going to be increased by one each time, so there is no dramatic shift in the ranking. Furthermore, elements are inserted or deleted from the catalog only in rare occasions, while requests are much more numerous and frequent. What is the best data structure to implement this?

These are the options that I have considered:

- a `std::map<ContentElement, unsigned int>` mapping contents to the number of requests they received. Not a good choice, as it requires me to dump everything to a list and sort it whenever I want to know the ranking of a content, which is very often.
- a `boost::multi_index_container` with two indexes, a hashed_unique for the ContentElement and an ordered_not_unique for the number of requests. This allows me to quickly retrieve a content in order to update its number of requests and to keep the container sorted as I do this through a `modify` call, but my understanding of the ordered index is that it still forces me to iterate through all its element in order to figure the rank of a content - I could not figure a simple way of extracting the position in the ranking from the ordered iterator.
- a `boost::bimap` between content elements and ranking position, supported by an external sorted vector storing the number of requests per content. Essentially the rank of a content would also represent the index of the vector element with its number of requests. This allows me to do everything I want to do (e.g., easily go from content to rank and viceversa) and sorting the vector after a new request should require at most two swaps in the bimap. However it feels clumsy and error-prone as I could easily loose sync between the map and the vector and then everything would fall apart.

My guts tell me there must be a much simpler and more elegant way of handling this, but I could not find it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your idea with the bimap + vector is not bad. If properly encapsulated it seems like a perfectly good (and elegant) solution.

Comment: Have a vector of ContentElement* sorted by their rank, taking into account the pointer, assuming they are "permanently" stored elsewhere. Sort the vector again after every change in rank. If the vector is mostly already sorted, sorting it again should be fast. This isn't the optimal solution, but might be fast enough for your needs. It can be improved later.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do a full sort. The key insight here is that a ranking can only change by +1 or -1 when it is accessed. I would do the following...

Keep the element in a container of your choice, e.g.

```
map< elementId, elementInstance >
```

Maintain a linked list of element rankings, something like this:

```
list< rankingInstance >
```

The rankingInstance has a pointer to an elementInstance and the value of the current rank and current number of accesses.  On access, you:

1. access the element in the map
2. get its current rank, and access count
3. update the count
4. using the current rank, access the linked list
5. check the neighbors
6. swap position in list if necessary
7. if swapping occurred, go back and update the two elements whose rank changed

Answer (score 0):

It may seem so simple, but my suggestion is to use `Bubble Sort` on your list. Since, `Bubble Sort` compares and switches only the adjacent elements, which is your case, simply one up or one down move in the ranking. Your vector may keep the **'Rank'** as key, **'ContentHash'** as value in a vector. A map containing **'Content'** or **'Content Reference'** will also needed. I hope this very simple approach gives some insights about your problem.